# IPTABLES - drop from one subnet to another

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I'm trying to isolate a LAN subnet from accessing another with iptables.

Router #1 (192.168.0.1): 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0

Router #2 (192.168.2.1): 192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0, gateway: 192.168.0.1

On router #1, I need incoming packets from router #2 clients to allow WAN access but drop to all other 192.168.0.* destinations. How?

For example, a client of router #2 with address 192.168.2.10 trying to establish an SSH connection to 192.168.0.100 sould block.

I tried this command:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0 -d 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 
-j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

After your

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0 -d 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 -j DROP
```

add another rule

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0 -d 0.0.0/0.0.0.0 -j ACCEPT
```

The second rule will only get packets which are not matched by the first. The order of the rules is important.